# Video flickering and freezing on ubuntu 22.04, did not on ubuntu 20.04

Tags: drivers, nvidia, 22.04

I have a old system HP-xw4600-Workstation with a NVIDIA G84GL [Quadro FX 1700]
When I had Ubuntu 20.04 I had no issues with flickering and freezing but on Ubuntu 22.04 I do have flickering and freezing.

```
focal (20.04LTS) (misc): NVIDIA binary driver - version 340.108
340.108-0ubuntu5 - amd64
Kernel: latest from apt upgrade - 5.15.0.67-generic

jammy (22.04LTS) (misc): Transitional package for xserver-xorg-video-nouveau
340.108-0ubuntu8 - amd64
Kernel: latest from apt upgrade - 6.5.0-21-generic

HP-xw4600-Workstation:~$ sudo apt-get install nvidia-340
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
nvidia-340 is already the newest version (340.108-0ubuntu8).
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.

HP-xw4600-Workstation:~$ uname -a
Linux HP-xw4600-Workstation 6.5.0-21-generic 
#21~22.04.1-Ubuntu SMP PREEMPT_DYNAMIC Fri Feb  9 13:32:52 UTC 2 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

When I go to additional drivers on 22.04, I do not see any options

I would stick with 20.04 but my wifi dongles do not work with it.

**Update**:

I am dual booting with 20.04 and 22.04

I just got the wireless NIC to work using the following on 20.04:
HP-xw4600-Workstation:~$ lsusb | grep -i realtek
Bus 002 Device 002: ID 0bda:f179 Realtek Semiconductor Corp. 802.11n

[How can I add a tethered Android phone on Linux (Ubuntu and Raspberry Pi OS)?](https://support.speedify.com/article/564-tether-android-linux)

[use-RTL8188FTV-on-linux](https://github.com/1999AZZAR/use-RTL8188FTV-on-linux)

I'm just going to stick with 20.04 for now. Too bad it's only supported until Apr 2025

Comment: I don't think 340 nvidia will work with kernels 6.0 and above any more. https://nvidia.custhelp.com/app/answers/detail/a_id/3142/